# Late binding of word in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, powerpoint, late-binding

I am developing an application which need to interact with 2003, 2007, 2010 versions of MSWord and PPT. I read some articles and found that Late binding is the best option.

Could somebody post some sample code how to do it for word and PPT?

Like how to get the running instances of application irrespective of their version?

Comment: Why is this tagged `pp`? What does that mean?

Comment: I would guess pp should be PowerPoint?

Comment: Yes..Powerpoint. Is that right tag? Excuse me if not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the Ms Word / PowerPoint object libraries which make the com intero really quite simple from .net. There is a nice step by step here for the word:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx

Along with the obligatory Microsoft tutorial:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384

There is a good article on late binding with COM here:

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Using-Late-Bound-COM-Objects/

Though you may want to heed the warning Microsoft give about the performance implications of using late binding of COM when early binding is available!

Alternatively you may want to take a look at the [aspose Libraries](http://www.aspose.com/categories/product-family-packs/aspose.total-product-family/default.aspx) for office file manipulation if you want a nice api and prefer to avoid COM. There pricy but I have used them extensively and find them far superior from a dev point of view.

Comment: Thanks Roja.. That was helpful :) Let me try

Comment: No problem! May be good to community wiki anything additional you find on your way!

Comment: If you're using .Net 4 you should also look at the "dynamic" keyword which improves com interop usability.

Comment: Keep in mind that the interop libraries are +mostly+ compatible all the way back to office 2000. What this means is that you should be able to add a reference to the Office 2000 type libs, and use early binding for MOST of your bindings, but resort to late bound references for those few objects/methods that didn't exist in 2000 (or that changed from 2000 to 2010). I do a LOT of that in my cross system addins.

Comment: If you feel that this answered your question could I please ask that you mark it as "answered" (click on the tick) so that others can identify it as such in the future.

Answer (score 1):

NetOffice (http://netoffice.codeplex.com) is a free set of version-independent interop assemblies for Office. It supports all Office versions and even tells you which Office versions support a particular method:

[image: NetOffice version info]